# Git unable to commit or rollback deleted file

Tags: android, git

I have two files in my android repo, :ls and :ls.pub.

[image]

When I clone the repo they are always missing and unstaged as deleted

[image]

If I commit the change, I receive "Changes not staged for commit: modified: :ls modified: :ls.pub"

if I stage them I receive "pathspec ':ls.pub' did not match any files"

If I do a git checkout I get "error: unable to create file :ls: File exists"

If I rollback I get "Error:pathspec ':ls.pub' did not match any file(s) known to git"

How can I remove or ignore them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AIMIN PAN's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68629843/1256452) (to avoid "odd" characters like `:` in path names) is good.  Git *does* allow `:` in path names, but `:` is a special *first* character in *pathspecs*, so it must be quoted or avoided.

The simplest method of doing that is usually to add `./` in front:

```
$ echo foo >':ls'
$ git add :ls
fatal: pathspec ':ls' did not match any files
$ git add ./:ls
$ git status --short
A  :ls
```

An alternative is to use double colon or `:(literal)`, e.g.:

```
$ git rm :ls
fatal: pathspec ':ls' did not match any files
$ git rm ':(literal):ls'
error: the following file has changes staged in the index:
    :ls
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
$ git rm :::ls
error: the following file has changes staged in the index:
    :ls
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
```

Note that a colon in a path name will trip up Windows systems.  Again, *Git* can handle it (with care), but not every OS can.

Answer (score 1):

Advise: stop using special characters in your file names.

Well I also want to know if colon ":" is supported character in git file name or not, but really don't have time to dig it out... On my Windows it is not allowed in file name.

If there is a strong reason to use : in file name, you should be prepared for numerous problems.